# Select files from 3 columns in mysql and zip them

Tags: php, mysql

I have database table where I store file names. They are stored in 3 columns and in each columns can be stored multiple files separated with comma. Like this: `file_id`, `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3` are column names

```
file_id | file_1                     | file_2                  | file_3 
   1      file_1.txt, file_1.1.txt.. | file_2.txt,file_2.2.txt | file_3.txt,file_3.3.txt
```

I hope is clear what is look like. I want with select to take all files names and then look in the folder and download in zip. So what I have until now is

```
$filePath = 'uploads/';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE file_id = 1"; // just for testing
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    //$result->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetch();    

foreach(['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3'] as $col){
    if (file_exists($filePath . $resArray[$col])){
        $valid_files[] = $resArray[$col];
    }
}

if(count($valid_files > 0)){
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip_name = "zipfile.zip";
    if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
        $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
    }

    foreach($valid_files as $res){

        $zip->addFile($filePath.$res['file_1']);
        $zip->addFile($filePath.$res['file_2']);
        $zip->addFile($filePath.$res['file_3']);

    }
  //print_r($valid_files);
  $zip->close();
   // zip download
}
```

When I run the code I've got errors

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'file_1' in ...
Warning: Illegal string offset 'file_2' in ...
Warning: Illegal string offset 'file_3' in ...
```

UPDATE:

`print_r($res);` contain only 1 file from `file_1` column

> file_1.txt

`print_r($resArray);` contain all files from all columns.. and the strange things is that each file is 2 times in array

> Array ( [file_1] => file_1.txt [0] => file_1.txt [file_2] => file_2.txt , [1] => file_2.txt , [file_3] => file_3.txt ,file_3.3.txt .jpg,file_3.3.txt,file_3.3.txt,file_3.3.txt, [2] => file_3.3.txt,file_3.3.txt,file_3.3.txt,file_3.3.txt,file_3.3.txt, )

Comment: What does `$res` contains in your `foreach($valid_files)` and `$resArray` in `foreach(['file_1', ...])`?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change a bit this part to:

```
foreach(['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3'] as $col){
    $items = explode(',', $resArray[$col]);
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        if (file_exists($filePath . trim($item))){
             $valid_files[] = $filePath . trim($item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it like here:

```
foreach($valid_files as $res){
   $zip->addFile($res);
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. This way is downloading only 1 file from first column.

Comment: Then use explode function before "file_exists($filePath . $resArray[$col])" and then check each item and add it into valid_files array

Comment: Finally it downloaded all files. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a problem in the host.. I've got error 500 and the site crash. This is due to `eAccelerator` and the `PHP version is 5.39`. Do you have idea how to change the arrays to stop crashing. The problem is this caching plugin on the host